# Node.js "ignore" $sort in a collection.aggregate query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This could be a dumb question, but I'm desperate already! I need to do this query:

```
db.clients.aggregate(
{
  $group: {
      _id: '$enterprise',
      lodging_days: { $sum: '$lodging_days' }
  }
},
{
  $sort : {
    lodging_days: -1
  }
})
```

And, if I copy this on the mongo bash, I returned this: [Bash Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZNnD.jpg)
(Sorry, I can't upload images yet)
JUST LIKE I WANT! 
But, when I put the query on node:

```
router.get('/query', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var clients=db.get('clients');

  clients.aggregate(
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$enterprise',
        lodging_days: { $sum: '$lodging_days' }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        'lodging_days': -1
      }
    },
    function(e, data){
      res.json(data);
    }
  );
});
```

This "ignore" the $sort and return me this: [Interface Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgQAP.jpg)
Now, my question are... Why!? And what can I make to fix it?

Comment: Try to wrap your pipeline into array.  `db.collection.aggregate( [ { <stage> }, ... ] )`

Comment: The way you call `aggregate` does not soom to match how the API says you should be calling it. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#aggregate

Comment: From your link:

// Execute aggregate, notice the pipeline is expressed as an Array
`collection.aggregate([])`
I mean you need to do next `clients.aggregate([your code with group, sort and function]);`

Comment: @VladislavKievski Oh!! That's the way! It's work! Thanks! Plz Post this like an answer, so I can validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to wrap your pipeline into array.

```
router.get('/query', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var clients=db.get('clients');

  clients.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$enterprise',
        lodging_days: { $sum: '$lodging_days' }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        'lodging_days': -1
      }
    }],
    function(e, data){
      res.json(data);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It need to wrap only the aggregate commands, the function goes outside. 

router.get('/query', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var clients=db.get('clients');

  clients.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$enterprise',
        lodging_days: { $sum: '$lodging_days' }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        'lodging_days': -1
      }
    }],
    function(e, data){
      res.json(data);
    }
  );
});